# Print string pointer causes corrupted output in C

Tags: c, string, function, pointers, printf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct cal {
    int date;
    int time;
    int importance;
    char title[256];
    char description[256];
};

int count;


void change_Cal (struct cal *calendar) {
    for (long long int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

        int year = 0, month = 0, day = 0;
        year = calendar[i].date / 10000;
        month = (calendar[i].date - 10000 * year) / 100;
        day = calendar[i].date % 100;
        printf("%04d.%02d.%02d.  ", year, month, day);

        int hour, min;
        hour = calendar[i].time / 100;
        min = calendar[i].time % 100;

        printf("%02d:%02d  %d  %s  %s\n",hour,min,calendar[i].importance, calendar[i].title, calendar[i].description);

    }

}

int main() {
    struct cal *calendar;

    //struct cal calendar[1024] = { 0, };
    printf("please input the number of the calender.\n>");
    scanf("%d", &count);
    calendar = (struct cal *)malloc(sizeof(struct cal)*count);
    calendar = (struct cal *)calloc(count, sizeof(struct cal));

    printf("input calendars.\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        printf(">");
        scanf("%d %d %d %c %c", &calendar[i].date, &calendar[i].time, &calendar[i].importance, calendar[i].title, calendar[i].description);
        printf("\n");
    }
    change_Cal(calendar);
}
```

The

```
printf("%02d:%02d  %d  %s  %s\n",hour,min,calendar[i].importance, calendar[i].title, calendar[i].description);
```

part is not working.
Some data is corrupted too.

```
Input : 20180927 0900 0 iiii  
Output: 2018.09.27.  09:00  0  i  i  
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 12.588 s
```

I think some pointers are the problem.
What's the problem?

Comment: What's the expected output? It seems ok to me.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest

Comment: Did you debug to check that the data is OK and really only the printing is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use this

```
scanf("%d %d %d %c %c", &calendar[i].date, &calendar[i].time, &calendar[i].importance, calendar[i].title, calendar[i].description);
```

to read this

```
20180927 0900 0 iiii
^        ^    ^ ^^
%d       %d  %d cc
```

So you get a number, a number, a number, a character ('i') and a character ('i').
Did you notice the risk of confusing a number with a leading 0 with an octal number?
The blank in the format string between the two expected characters, will be parsed as "take any present whitespace" which for "iiii" is "no whitespace".
You will leave in the input stream "ii\n"; which will confuse the next attempt to scan a number and make it fail. I.e. the return value of the next scan-attempt (which you ignore in your code) will be 0, while it should be 5.

To fix read about all the things that can go wrong with complex input scanning via scanf:
http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html

Then change to something which can read strings instead of character, but probably not scanf().

Comment: Thank you very much for this kind answer. I solved the problem using 'scanf("%d %d %d %s %s", &calendar[i].date, &calendar[i].time, &calendar[i].importance, &calendar[i].title, &calendar[i].description);'. Now it scans strings instead of characters.